# equivalence between integration of $n$-form and Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open (precompact), and I want to integrate $\omega = f dx^1 \wedge \cdots dx^n$, where $f$ is smooth on a larger open set $\Omega \supset U$. Since $U$ is precompact, $f$ is Riemann integrable. By definition,

$$\int_U \omega = \int_U f dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n := \int_U f dx^1\cdots dx^n$$
Note that RHS is Riemann integration and LHS is "some integration of $n$-form." RHS is clearly well-defined using standard definition of integration (i.e. take partition of $U$ (or some collection of rectangles that well-approximates $U$ and sum over the rectangle).

Now, I am wondering why LHS is defined as Riemann integration of $f$ over $U$. On LHS, we have a $dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ that preserves properties of anti-symmetric $n$-form, and when we put it in integration, we suddenly convert it to $dx^1 \cdots dx^n$. What guarantees that this is a consistent definition?

Comment: How do you mean '*consistent*'? Do you worry about the fixed order of $dx^i$ on LHS?

Comment: @Berci Yes. Switch the order of $dx^i$, and LHS can be negative of RHS.

Comment: Just don't worry about it. *This* is the definition, so if you apply an odd permutation, the LHS indeed becomes its negative. However, in changed order it's *not expected* to be equal to the Riemann integral.

Comment: I see. So IF I define $\int_U \omega := \int_U -f dx^2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n := \int_U -f dx_2 dx_1 \cdots dx^n$, then $\int_U \omega = -\int_U f dx^1\cdots dx^n$ according to this definition. Is this correct?

Comment: Orientation is required for integrating a differential form, for precisely this reason.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is there a way to calculate volume of an unorientable hypersurface?

Comment: Yes, for volume you can integrate $|dV|$, which is called a density. But think about notions of flux that show up in physics; here you need an orientation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you.